# Possible to run Visual Studio Performance Wizard on XNA Windows Phone 7 app?

Tags: visual-studio, performance, windows-phone-7, xna

Anxious to try our Visual Studio 2010 performance tools, but when I launch the performance wizard, it does not enumerate my XNA Windows Phone project as a project it can analyze, and instead just enumerates the XNA content project in my solution.

I installed VS 2010 SP1 hoping that because SP1 added performance tool support to silverlight, it would work for XNA Windows Phone as well. But it doesn't look like it.

Has anyone gotten this to work?

Comment: Can you confirm you're using the "Windows Phone Performance Analysis" from the Mango beta tools?

Answer (score 0):

The emulator has a performance output (the numbers down the side). I would suggest using this, desktop performance and phone performance are not directly linked.